# How to cache $routeProvider templateUrl with gulp-angular-templatecache

Tags: angularjs, caching, gulp

I have following code to cache the template. I am using gulp to pre-cache the templates. But I am not able to used it for router urls.

```
'use strict';

var config         = require('../config');
var gulp           = require('gulp');
var templateCache  = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

// Views task
gulp.task('views', function() {

// Put our index.html in the dist folder
gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist.root));

// Process any other view files from app/views
return gulp.src(config.views.src)
.pipe(templateCache({
  standalone: true
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.views.dest));

});

//in router
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

 $routeProvider.when('/todos', {
  templateUrl: 'views/todos.html',
  controller: 'TodoCtrl',
 });
});
```

Can anybody help me on how can i use the cached template in this router?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. While template cache we have to five the actual path of the templates else it will take the relative url. If your templates are in **views** directory then we have to update it like this...

```
templateCache({
  root:'views', 
  standalone: false
})
```